# how to set dynamic path in background-image: url()

Tags: html, angular

this is my html code and i want to set dynamic url in my my background-image:

```
<div class="top-banner-bg" style="background-image: url({{ imageToShowURL }})">
</div>
```

and here is my code in my ts file in angular:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.imageService.getHomePageBanner().subscribe(data => {
      if (data['ok']) {
        this.imageToShowURL = 'http://194.135.90.60/Back_end_Media/Media/Screenshot_from_2018-10-25_17-31-43.png';
      }
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
    }
```

but in my html code this style does not work.

how can i fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ngStyle` to do that

```
<div class="top-banner-bg" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + imageToShowURL + ')'}"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `get` property to return the style and use the `ngStyle` directive

```
<div class="top-banner-bg" [ngStyle]="getBackgroundStyle">
```

```
get getBackgroundStyle(){
    return {
        'background-image':'url(' + this.imageToShowURL  + ')'
    }
}
```